# Android - Difference between 'clickable' and 'contextClickable' attributes?

Tags: android

I'm making a custom compound view and working in Android Studio. I want the view to react on clicks as a single object. What's the difference between 'clickable' and 'contextClickable' attributes and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2):

the 'clickable' attribute is related to the onClickListener callback

the 'contextClickable' attribute is related to the onContextClickListener callback and has been introduced in API 23

My guess is that a contextclick refers to a right-mouse click.

In your case you should definitively use the 'clickable' attribute.